# A shortcut for class member declarations

Tags: c++, coding-style

I've got to add a bunch of members to a class. I would like to add a macro such as this:

```
#define MEMBER(TYPE,NAME) \
    private: TYPE m_##NAME; \
    public: TYPE get##NAME() const { return m_##NAME; } \
    public: void set##NAME(TYPE in##NAME) { m_##NAME = in##NAME; }
```

and then use it to add the members to the class:

```
class foo {
    MEMBER(std::string, OutputDir);
    MEMBER(int, MaxIterations);
    MEMBER(double, OptimizationCutoff);
    // And a couple dozen more members...
    public:
    // The rest of the class declarations
};
```

The intend is obviously to shortcut multiple instances of code like this, 3 lines for each of the multitude of class members:

```
private: std::string m_OutputDir;
public: std::string getOutputDir() const { return m_OutputDir; }
public: void setOutputDir(std::string inOutputDir) { m_OutputDir = inOutputDir; }
```

Are there any consideration against coding like that?

Comment: Use another level of indirection and set up an editor macro to generate proper code, not macros.

Comment: How many member variables are you intending to have? maybe that is problem. Seems also a bit inflexible, if I say want to have only read access on one variable should i then use yet another macro?

Comment: Macros are largely avoided because they are pretty damn dangerous, hard to write well, and hard to read. For example, try making a std::pair<int,int> in your code (you can do it with a type def, but oh man is it annoying)

Comment: Looks like Q_PROPERTY: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html

Comment: If you have a public get & set, what is the point of making the member private?

Comment: @koodawg: Because it's much easier to add logging, business logic, etc. later on if existing code is already going through accessor/mutator functions.

Comment: @Bill:  Not in the face of these macros, I don't think.

Comment: Would "your team members becoming raging psychopaths who want to do really bad things to you" be a "consideration against coding like that"?

Comment: @claptrap: the count of members is immaterial to the question. In this particular case the class represents parameters for a mathematical model of a physical system that is naturally complicated.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I'm not a fan of these macros, but it can be useful throw functions around what would otherwise be a public member, just in case you want to change the implementation details of that member later.

Comment: @Bill:  I disagree with the idea of wrapping something in a function "just in case," but that is 1) tangential, and B) not popular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'd point out an observation.  The macros you've defined here seem to be ***completely useless***.  I get what you're trying to do -- with one line of code declare a member variable and simple getter and setter methods.

I would counter:  if you're just exposing these member variables with simple getters & setters, why not just make the member variable `public` and be done with it?

> Are there any consideration against coding like that?

Yes, all the usual concerns about Evil misuse of macros.  Let's go through a few as they pertain here.

### You are creating a secret language that only you will know.

Code that looks like this:

```
class foo {
    MEMBER(std::string, OutputDir);
    MEMBER(int, MaxIterations);
    MEMBER(double, OptimizationCutoff);
    // And a couple dozen more members...
    public:
    // The rest of the class declarations
};
```

at a glance might be *somewhat* obvious in it's construction, but there are many details that are obscured when it comes time to maintain or extend either `foo`, one of the members, or the macro itself.

For example, in just glancing at this I get the idea that you are declaring a member `OutputDir`, but there's really no indication if it's a data member or a member function.  If it's a member function, what is the return type?  What are the parameters?  How would I declare a member function template?  What are the template parameters?

You have built a syntax here that might save a keystroke or two when first typing the code, but can generate hours and hours of frustration and head-banging when someone needs answers to any of these questions.  Since it isn't documented or supported by anybody but you, your macros end up being akin to a secret language that only you know.

### Macros are difficult to debug

When degugging code that uses a macro, you see the substituted text -- not the macro or how it was called.  This can be very confusing.

### Macros have no namespace

Macros are a brute-force text substitution tool.  They do not respect any namespace or scope, and are universally applied everywhere they are defined and invoked.  This steps around the C++ type system completely and lets your write code that would otherwise evoke an error.

### Macros have strange and unintended side effects and are applied in places you didn't expect.

A common example is the definition of the `min` and `max` macro by VisualStudio, which clobbers the functions by the same name in the Standard Library.  Side effects can be bizarre and, as mentioned, very difficult to debug.

Comment: Accepted the answer: don't use macros. A follow-up question though: is there a reasonable alternative to writing 3 virtually identical lines for each of 20-30 parameters? Of course I can do that manually, but I'm looking for something more elegant that, among other things, won't inflate the header file size.

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives.  I mean obviously I'm a fan of just making the members public, but if you're not a fan of that then I would look in to using some kind of code transform.  There are programs that do this for you.  I've forgotten them all now but will try to recall some.

Comment: @Michael:  Like something that sucks in an XSL file and spits out C++ code.  I'm racking my brain...

Comment: Sometimes code generation is not an acceptable solution: [link](http://jessicarbrown.com/images/ft-cpp-loop.gif)

Comment: @Michael:  I like the cartoon.